# Website to process file with custom script and print output

Tags: python, automation, web-services, drag-drop

I want to quickly build, without coding, a website with the following functionality:

- Users can drag-and-drop a file onto the website (or otherwise easily provide a file as an input)
- The website then processes the file using a python script that I provide
- The website prints the output from the script for the user to see

The reason I've said it should be a website is that I want it to be easily useable for someone with no coding background. If there is another way of achieving this level accessibility without using a website, that would solve my problem.

The closest I've found is https://anvil.works/features. However, it seems like this might require more coding in to configure the user interface than is ideal for me.

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660299/start-python-script-from-client-side) but it had no good answers and I don't want a solution that can be built by someone (me) who has no experience of building websites.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, look into Django & build your website in Python. Welcome aboard & good luck

Comment: Also, search for `python fiddle`. With luck you might find one that you can host yourself.